# Looping until condition is met and writing to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting... I want to execute a command every 5 seconds and write the output to a file which is currently in json format and then use jq to read a particular key from json and print it to console.

I started using `watch` but echo `watch -n 5 command > myFile.json` doesnt seem to create a file. Is there any other way?

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a loop with sleep, eg :

```
while true; do command > myFile.json; sleep 5; done
```

Note if you want to **append** the command output to your json file, use >> instead of >

To break the loop based on a condition :

```
 while :  
 do 
   command > json_file 
   [[ $(jq_command json_file) != "expected_text" ]] || break 
   sleep 5 
 done
```

Comment: But I assume this would run infinitely... If I give while a condition, is there a way I can read the file and check is one of the json key has my expected value and if yes, terminate the loop

Comment: `is there a way` - yes there is. Start a new question and post what have you tried. Use `jq` to parse json.